# How can I select the filename with the highest version number?

Tags: bash

I wrote a build script and would like to be able to select the latest version of the script when it installs, e.g. the package name is package_X.X.X.tar.gz and there are multiple copies.

Is there a way to point the build command to package_Y.tar.gz? where Y=max(X.X.X)?

Comment: You could use a regexp to extract the version information, but I don't think you'll be able to get by with just regexp here.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If the files are equal except for the version numbers, you could use something like

```
ls -v | tail -n 1
```

From the man-page of `ls`:

```
...
-v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text
...
```

Example usage:

```
$ ls
package_1.5.7.9.tar.gz  package_2.5.3.9.tar.gz  package_4.6.1.0.tar.gz
$ ls -v | tail -n 1
package_4.6.1.0.tar.gz
```

Comment: keep in mind that this only works if the prefixes before the version numbers are the same.

Comment: Thanks, to remove extraneous files I'll use: ls -v package*tar.gz | tail -n 1

Comment: I am not sure this solution would work perfectly? How would it tell the difference between 1.9 and 1.10, would it not think 9 is higher than 10 since it would be treating it as a string char by char?

Comment: @WORMSS I've created an empty directory that I've populated with foo-<version> files and tried it. It works as expected: 1.10 is a higher version number than 1.9 and the file is placed accordingly. It must check to see if there is something that looks like a version number in the file name and then treats this bit as a version number rather than a general string.

Comment: Just a heads up that 'ls -v' under OSX works differently: "-v      Force unedited printing of non-graphic characters"

Comment: As already pointed out, this doesn't work for versions like <name>-5.10.9 and <name>-5.10.10 (like the Linux kernel with this version), where 5.10.10 is the newer and "ls -v" will list 5.10.9 first...

Comment: @luttztfz, hmm, listing 5.10.9 first seems logical? That's "cronological order". 9 comes before 10 so to speak. If you want newest first, try adding `-r`.

Comment: @aioobe, you're right. I guess I wasn't paying attention at what "tail -n 1" does... Thanks!

Comment: Natural Sort came with GNU Coreutils v7 and is also available in the `sort` command.

```
-V, --version-sort
              natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```